# How to restrict user to access iframe in separate tab?

Tags: html, redirect, iframe

> On my index page there are two links for Login and Signup and one iframe

**I have designed both(Login and signup) pages separately**
Now i want to force both pages to be opened **only in iframe** not in a separate tab
and if someone tries to access directly redirect them to index page.
here is my code...

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
 <title></title>
</head>
<body>
<a href="login.php" target="frame">Login</a> <a href="signup.php">Signup</a>
<iframe src="" name="frame" frameborder="0"></iframe>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please post your code.

Comment: Code added but nothing is wrong with the code, i want both pages should be opened **only** in iframe not in a separate tab

Comment: What is your problem right now?

Comment: The pages (login.php and signup.php) can be accessed directly. But i don't want it to be.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I just found the Best way to do it with Javascript..

```
var myUrl = 'http://localhost/test/index.php';
if(window.top.location.href !== myUrl) {
    window.top.location.href = myUrl;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can add the following to the `head` of your HTMl document to make it automatically redirect if it is not loaded inside an iframe:

```
<script>
window.onload = function(){
   if (top === self) {
     //not inside iframe
     location = 'url';
   }
}
</script>
```

JSFiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/xjqyrsd7/

Comment: Sorry, Not working It is redirecting every-time (In frame and in separate page) i just want that "if you tries to access login.php directly you must be redirected to index page..

Comment: Thank You ! It is working but not quick redirect i'm able to see login.php page for approx 1 sec. I just found the other way to do it I have posted it as answer.

Comment: @ShubhamPrajapat Immediate redirection may not always be possible, considering your network speed. Your way of doing it will have the same problem.

Comment: I Agree with you but understand the difference-> Our ways of doing are not exact same i'm being redirected in same time with both ways but in your code i'm able to see the loaded content of login.php but in my way i'm unable to see the content while redirection and the same i want...

Comment: @ShubhamPrajapat Generally it's good practice to indicate to users that they are being redirected.